# How to ensure Windows 10 is safe from critical security hole reported by NSA on 2020-01-14?

Tags: windows, windows-10, updates

[All over](https://www.forbes.com/sites/daveywinder/2020/01/14/windows-10-extraordinarily-serious-security-warning-for-900-million-users/#2851b336690c) the [news](https://www.theverge.com/2020/1/14/21065563/microsoft-windows-security-flaw-nsa-patch-attribution-cryptography-update) today (2020-01-14) is the story that the NSA and Microsoft have reported a critical security vulnerability in Windows 10.

But I haven't been able to find clear instructions about how to ensure that Windows Update has worked properly.

When I click the Start button and then then type "winver" and click "Run command", I see that I have Windows 10 Version 1803 (OS Build 17134.191)

Windows > Settings > "Update & Security" > "See what's new in the latest update", it bounces me to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4043948/windows-10-whats-new-in-recent-updates, which doesn't seem to mention security at all.

The Windows Update feature itself seems flaky, confusing, and unreliable.

I'm the most tech-savvy in my large extended family, and I generally try to help others (especially older generations) keep their systems working well, but right now I'm struggling to find a set of steps I can walk them through to confirm that their systems are no longer vulnerable.

Answer (score 3):

The relevant patches that must be download and applied are described in the following [MSRC Portal page](https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-US/security-guidance/advisory/CVE-2020-0601).

Matching the OS version number to your system, clicking the article number brings you to a page showing the build number your system should show after you patch.

For example, for Windows 10 Version 1809 for x64-based systems, [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4534293/windows-10-update-kb4534293) shows the resulting build number (OS Build 17763.973)

Comment: The question was simply "how to check" that the patch has been applied. Now the answer explains that.

Comment: @schroeder Mine now says Version 1903 (OS Build 18362.592), so I guess Windows Update gave me some other upgrades along the way.