# CVE-2020-0601 (CRYPT32.DLL exploit) standalone patch?

Tags: windows-10, patching

Is there any standalone patch for  CVE-2020-0601 (CRYPT32.DLL exploit) besides installing Windows 10 latest cumulative update?

Or is there  other ways to mitigate this exploit, when immediate patching with CU isn't possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are specific patches that can be downloaded for each Windows version that is affected by the CVE.

I've provided [a more detailed answer on this related question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/224214/how-to-ensure-windows-10-is-safe-from-critical-security-hole-reported-by-nsa-on/224215#224215), about how to find and download the correct patch for your Windows release version.